# error on query , trying to make a search by keywords

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a variable and an user_name i want to search on a string(function_description) of the user_name for it

whats wrong with this :

```
$function_keywords = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['function_keywords']);
if($function_keywords=="" || empty($function_keywords)){
    redirect("show.php?functions=PHP");
}
//trim whitespace from the stored variable
$trimmed = trim($function_keywords);
//separate key-phrases into keywords
$trimmed_keywords = explode(" ",$trimmed);
// Build SQL Query for each keyword entered
foreach ($trimmed_keywords as $trimm){
// MySQL "MATCH" is used for full-text searching.
//this code is ebv weird , should check out soon!
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM functions
          WHERE isEnabled=1 AND isPrivate=0
          AND function_description LIKE '{$trimm}' 
          AND user_name='{$user_name}'   
          ";
 // Execute the query to  get number of rows that contain search kewords
 $results=mysql_query ($query,$connection);
```

Comment: Using `LIKE '{$trimm}'` is same as `=`, maybe you would need to include `%{$trimm}%` ?

Comment: `$function_keywords == ""` is redundant since you are already checking for `empty($function_keywords)`. Just use empty here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's highly inefficient. If someone puts in 5 keywords, you'd be running the search 5 times and getting 5 sets of results. Try something more along these lines:

```
$words = $_POST['function_keywords'];
if ($words == '') {
    ... abort ...
}

$parts = trim(explode(' ', $words));
$clauses = array();
foreach($parts as $part) {
    $clauses[] = "function_description LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($part) . "%'";
}

$clause = implode(' OR ' , $clauses);

$sql = "SELECT .... WHERE (isEnabled=1) AND (isPrivate=1) AND (user_name='$user_name') AND ($clause)";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

This'll build up a long series of `or` statements for each keyword specified, and run the whole thing as a single query.

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM functions 
      WHERE isEnabled=1 AND isPrivate=1
      AND user_name=($user_name)
      AND ($clause) ";  //this is not working , why ?

Comment: This is more efficient because most likely it will be scanning all the rows in the db, and it's best to scan just once. This is equivalent to stopping at a rest stop and everybody going, rather than stopping again at the next x number of rest stops. It's the "since we're already here" paradigm.

Comment: after a tried to echo back the value of $clause :  Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\xampp\htdocs\thinkgs\search.php on line 13

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\thinkgs\search.php on line 15

Comment: i did fix the problem and the query with a keywords of (test1 test2 test3) : $sql="SELECT * 
   FROM functions 
      WHERE isEnabled=1 AND isPrivate=1
      AND user_name=high
      AND function_description LIKE '%test1%' OR function_description LIKE '%test2%' OR function_description LIKE '%test3%' ";

Answer (score 2):

as far as "like" syntax goes you have to use the '%' symbol. if you query for

```
select * from table where column like '%yourkeyword%'
```

then it returns any rows with 'yourkeyword' inside the table column.

your statement will be true only if the column = 'yourkeyword'

Answer (score 1):

To see if the function_description contains the keyword you need to use '%' which stands for anything much the way '*' does in unix.  Try function_description LIKE '%{$trimm}%'